# Google ReCaptcha - Customize

Tags: php, customization, recaptcha

I am using Google ReCaptcha in my web site. Is it possible to limit the level of security. Basically what I want to do is, My page should only ask user to select whether "I am not a bot" option. I dont want to have image selections.

Any one know how to do this customization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u paste the full code here

Comment: Yes I can, but is there any configuration that we can set without hack the google's code?

Comment: You can use the Custom Captcha widget any time: https://www.custom-captcha.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just 1/100 users will see an image. Without this method 1/100 will be blocked or every bot could pass your captcha.
Without this extra validation ReCaptcha does not make sense.
 If you just want the "im not a bot button":

```
<button>Im not a Bot</button>
```

Comment: You comment makes sense. But my requirement here is different. In one place I need the full functional re-Captcha. In another place I need only the "Im not a Bot". Funny though, but its my requirement. In both places I have to use Google Re-Captcha.

Comment: ReCaptcha gives you Security and Usability. Switching of both is a bit senseless. Rewriting Googles Code is hell ( i tried to personify the google calender iframe). You could try but dont be frustrated

Comment: Understood. Thanks @Jonas w.